# android spinner onselectitemclick listener no triger

Tags: android, android-spinner

This is how i define the spinner

```
s_province = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s_province);
        ArrayAdapter<String> provinceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Data.provinces);
        provinceAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s_province.setAdapter(provinceAdapter);
        s_province.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

my class is implement from `OnItemSelectedListener` and i override this methods

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg1.getId()) {
        case R.id.s_province:
            Log.d("here", "there");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

but the `onItemSelect` is not triged , why please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. If you actually want to check if your method is working put a `Log` statement outside the `switch` or in the `default` case so that you can be *sure* the method is being called.
2. You should be using `arg2` since [that represents position](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html). Make your switch work with positions instead of whatever View is passed. Also rename your variables from the default names Eclipse assigns. `arg0,1,2, etc` are not helpful for you nor for anyone else looking at your code.

Eg

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
  Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"onItemSelected called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  int spinnerId = parent.getId();
  if (spinnerId == R.id.s_province)
  {
    switch (position)
    {
      case 0: 
        //do something if first position was clicked
      break:
      case 1:
        //do something else
        break;
      default: 
        //if for any reason no position matches.
        break;
    }
  }
  else if (spinnerId == R.other_id_in_xml)
  {
    switch (position)
    {
      case 0: 
        //do something if first position was clicked
      break:
      case 1:
        //do something else
        break;
      default: 
        //if for any reason no position matches.
        break;
    }
  }
  //etc
}
```

Comment: would you tell me the good variable names, Google's website is forbidden :(, i put toast in defalt and didn't work

Comment: @FernadoMargin Added a sample. Did you forget to call `.show()` on your Toast?

Comment: when i put `.show()` it works, i always didn't use `.show()` and it works , why now doesn't work?

Comment: and what should i do to make `switch` becaues i have 3 spinners and on each one select i want to do something, (sorry for my bad englihs)

Comment: @FernadoMargin `.show()` is always needed when using `makeText()`, so I'm not sure. As for having multiple spinners, you can compare the Id of the spinner, then make a switch based on position. Alternatively, you can also assign each Spinner its own `Listener`,

Comment: A--C the onItemSelect is triggerd now when i start the activity , not just when i select a item from spinner , why ?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't *ever* worked with Spinners, I can just read the API quite well :-). Maybe a default value of some sort?

Comment: is it because the spinner has a value when activity starts ?